# Does The 100 have a relationship to/with Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: reference, the-100, battlestar-galactica

So I recently(ish) watched the first season of *The 100* on Netflix and couldn't help but notice the similarities it had to *Battlestar Galactica* (specifically Ronald D. Moore's remake). This is both in terms of actors - goodness knows, *The 100* has had plenty of actors from both BSG and *Caprica* - and in terms of certain visuals (the space fleet bears some strong resemblances to the fleet in BSG). However, I'm not sure how much of that is just coincidence/natural crossover within various TV shows; due to direct inspiration/influence from BSG; or due to some of the creator(s)/producer(s)/etc. having also been involved in BSG. Does anybody know?

Comment: I felt exactly the same. As a matter of fact, the dilemmas are treated in a very similar way, although the pace is faster in this one, the resemblance for me is clear in writing, acting, direction and production. I feel soo good that I am not the only one thinking the same :) greetings from Colombia, South America.

Comment: Between the 12 colonies/stations/clans, 13th colony/clan, bomb plot, shooting Adama/Jaha, and even double crossing cylons, I just can't with this show.

Comment: Looks like the author of the 100 plagerized Battlestar Galactica if you ask me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The showrunner, [Jason Rothenberg, is a big fan of BSG](http://www.channel4.com/info/press/news/an-interview-with-executive-producer-jason-rothenberg-for-the-100). This might be an explanation, in parts.

> "How would you describe the genesis of the concept for The 100?
>
> The show is based on a book. Last year, I was looking for a pilot to
>   write and I had a meeting with the publisher. They told me about this
>   idea and it instantly blew my mind. I think I can honestly say it’s an
>   amazing idea because it wasn’t my idea and I’m not tooting my own horn
>   here – but it instantly touched all of the hot creative issues that I
>   was looking for.
>
> What creative issues were you looking for?
>
> I wanted to do a show with a *Lord of the Flies* theme – and that was
>   there in this story. ***Battlestar Galactica* is one of my favourite shows
>   of all time.** Well, this is like Battlestar Galactica in space. *Lost* is
>   also one of my favourite shows of all time – and this is like *Lost* on
>   the ground. It was a very easy decision for me to take on this
>   project."

Answer (score 4):

An [IMDb commmon cast/crew search](http://www.imdb.com/search/common) isn't really [yielding a lot of the same people](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0407362,tt2661044) at the [supervising to executive producer levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_producer#Types_of_television_producers), so my guess would be that it's simply the fact that both shows were shot in Vancouver and are drawing on the same acting,  production, and SFX pools.  And that you're liable to see similar crossover of cast/crew from BSG with other Vancouver-shot shows like, say, [Supernatural](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0407362,tt0460681).

Comment: Very possible - I wouldn't be surprised at all if this were the case. However I'm going to wait to see if there are any more answers just in case somebody has more info, especially as with shows like Supernatural - even Dollhouse, where any given guest star was very likely to have been on BSG - the actors appear as just that - occasional guest stars with one-off appearances. And the SFX, etc. aren't necessarily all that reminiscent of BSG in other shows. (As far as actors in The 100, I was very impressed by just how many BSG actors were cast in recurring roles.)

Comment: @ghostdog Completely agree. My answer is just a guess, after all.

Comment: I def think Battlestar is an influence and there are probably easter eggs to it (I know some people have sited LOST easter eggs as well), but I also know that the 100 is based on ongoing books by Kass Morgan...

Answer (score -2):

I did a search through IMDB a good while back and I remember seeing 2-3 crew members from BSG working on The 100. I can say for a fact that Wayne Rose directed episodes of BSG and one episode of The 100. Coincidentally I think that particular episode stood out to me as a very strong resemblance to BSG.

Comment: You should provide links